# Cannot debug UWP app on Simulator: foreground can not be acquired

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10

With Visual Studio for Windows, if I debug my Xamarin.Forms UWP app in "Local Machine" it works fine, but if I choose "Simulator", I get the following error when launching the debug session:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app '10509MyNameAndSurname.myappname_6k78edmmrpdam!App'. The activation request failed with error 'Activate Application failed as foreground can not be acquired in Windows Simulator'. See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

If I click Help, it sends me to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh972445(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), which doesn't really mention my problem above. Any way to fix this? The main reason I want to know if it runs this way is because I'm getting a lot of "Cannot launch App" errors from the Windows App Certification Kit.

I restarted the OS and tried with a Blank App (C#, UWP): and got a different error:

[image]

Then I retried debugging my app, and got yet a new error:

> Error     DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] An
>   internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>   deployment issues.

Comment: Could you launch the Simulator with pure blank UWP app?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT updated the question to answer your comment

Comment: Derive from error code 0x80073D05   *An error occurred while deleting the package's previously existing application data.
You can get this error if the simulator is running. Close the simulator. You can also get this error if there are files open in the app data (for example, if you have a log file open in a text editor).*  Please try to manually delete previous existing application and the project bin and obj folder.

Comment: ok closing the simulator first, it worked

Comment: gonna try again the Windows Certification Kit

Comment: Ok, please let me know the testing result.

Comment: next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60350735/544947

Comment: Our team member has follow up your next question, and if above is helpful, may I convert it as an answer for this question?