# Debugging UWP .NET app: Unhandled exception at 0x79A1CFAC (SharedLibrary.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0x00001007

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, corert

I've built a Xamarin.Forms app and when I try to debug its UWP frontend in `Debug|AnyCPU` mode I get this exception at launch:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x79A1CFAC (SharedLibrary.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0x00001007
```

Visual Studio wouldn't let me copy all the details to the clipboard so I had to take a screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio for Windows catches a crash when debugging]

If I run it in `Debug|x64` mode I get a completely different exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFEA232EC0 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in
>   MyApp.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal
>   exception has occurred (parameters: 0x000002225D634960,
>   0x0000000000000002).

And this time the CallStack panel is empty.

I'm at a loss at how to approach this problem.

Comment: UWP apps don't run in AnyCPU. Select x86 /x64

Comment: I updated the question to explain what happens with x64

Comment: try x86 and post which 3rd party nugets you use in the app

Comment: Does the same problem occur when you create a blank `Xamarin.Forms` project? Can you provide a minimum runnable demo?

Comment: does it work with x86 or does it still show the same error?

Comment: I found out this is an issue of F#'s printf; filed here https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/4954 and here https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8621

Comment: I have same problem executing in x64 release mode. How you solve this ?

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes are you using F#? if not, then this question is not related to your problem

Comment: @knocte I'm using UWP with CSharp